# Unble to click this button

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am unable to select this button. I have tried most of the locator i.e XPath, contain, CSS selector still not clicking.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAuc1.png)

In the above image link, the highlight shows the button to be clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to click the [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), not the [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span), the relevant [XPath locator](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies) would be something like:

```
//button[@title='Proceed to Checkout']
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Answer (score 0):

I'd try clicking by using X/Y coordinates with a macro tool like AppRobotic if you're running this on Windows. A similar question I saw was running into issues with the page continuing to load, which was preventing the click. If so, I usually try stopping the page load, and interacting with the page a bit, something like this should work for you:

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import Dispatch
x = win32com.client.Dispatch("AppRobotic.API")
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
# wait 20 seconds
x.Wait(20000)
# scroll down a couple of times in case page javascript is waiting for user interaction
x.Type("{DOWN}")
x.Wait(2000)
x.Type("{DOWN}")
x.Wait(2000)
# forcefully stop pageload at this point
driver.execute_script("window.stop();")
# if clicking with Selenium still does not work here, use screen coordinates
x.MoveCursor(xCoord, yCoord)
x.MouseLeftClick
x.Wait(2000)
```

Comment: cant you provide me simple code. as I want to implement it in selenium using java.

Answer (score 0):

Span is not clickable. You want to click the button instead. If you can provide the entire DOM element, I can create a xpath for you to use but based on what is shown,

```
ul.checkout-types > li > button
```

is your path. Using the variable from user Mike,

```
driver.click("ul.checkout-types > li > button");
```